# Building .net3.5 project programatically causes error MSB4067: The element <ImportGroup> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized

Tags: msbuild, .net-3.5

I have written code bellow to build .net3.5 project programmatically,

```
var engine = new Engine
            {
                DefaultToolsVersion = "3.5",
                BinPath =  @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5"
            };

            var logger = new FileLogger { Parameters = @"logfile=" + MsBuildLogPath};

            engine.RegisterLogger(logger);

            var properties = new BuildPropertyGroup();
            properties.SetProperty("Configuration", "release");
            properties.SetProperty("OutputPath", @"bin\Release\");
            properties.SetProperty("Platform", "Any CPU");
            properties.SetProperty("TargetFrameworkVersion", "3.5");
            properties.SetProperty("OutputPath", destinationPath + @"\Output");

            bool result = engine.BuildProjectFile(solutionPath, new[] { "rebuild" }, properties);
```

my msbuild path is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5" and since my builder project is based on .net3.5 and for some reasons **I cant update it to .net4**.

Compiling project causes error

```
 "error MSB4067: The element <ImportGroup> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized"
```

I know that updating my project to .net4 and using build engine 4.0 resolves my problem, but as I said before for some reason I cant update my project to to .net4 and switch build path to .net4/msbuild. So what can I do to fix this error?

This is my project file content that contains no ImportGroup tag!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{14D56AA1-C68E-4AC4-B114-CFD1A22B6D1C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Tosan.GeneratedProduct.GL.Common</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Tosan.GeneratedProduct.GL.Common</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\Output\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Tosan.Framework">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\Tosan.Framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Tosan.Framework.Interfaces">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\Tosan.Framework.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Tosan.Framework.Java">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\Tosan.Framework.Java.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Tosan.Global.Data">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\Tosan.Global.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ValidationFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f07bd240683f08a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\ValidationFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Enum\" />
    <Folder Include="Filter\" />
    <Folder Include="Interface\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Tosan.Framework, Version=3.17.6258.18262, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\Tosan.Framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Data\customer.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Data\CustomerDebit.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Tosan.Framework, Version=3.18.6429.18915, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\SharedDlls\Tosan.Framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

thank you.